# What procs Tal Rasha 4pc bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I know that Tal Rasha **2pc** gets procced by any elemental damage on enemies, whether they are from you, your pets (Familiar / Hydra), or Etched Sigil. (I'm not sure about your follower.)

And I know that Tal Rasha **6pc** gets procced from elemental attack skills that are cast by you (regardless of whether they actually hit anything), so they are not procced by attacks from your pets or Etched Sigil.

But how about Tal Rasha **4pc**? How is it procced? Can they be procced by your pets or Etched Sigil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do some tests. Seems like the 4pc bonus works similar to the 6pc bonus as Nzall suggested, but with one important difference...

With the 6pc bonus, once you get up to 4 stacks, you can maintain it with just **two** elements. Unfortunately, you can't do that with the 4pc bonus, which means you need to continuously cast all 4 elements to maintain the 100% resistance increase.

I suppose the description on Tal Rasha sort of indicates the above behaviour, but its worded a bit unclearly, as I didn't get the impression from reading it that alternating between just 2 elements will work.

Also, I found out in my tests that hydras **can** proc Tal Rasha 6pc. I read somewhere that hydra attacks are considered your attacks rather than pet attacks, and hence don't get bonuses from pet buffs like Enforcer gem and Tasker and Theo.

Comment: Hydra attacks do _not_ proc the Tal Rasha 6 pc.  However casting the hydra itself does.  So to keep up the bonus you need to recast the hydra every few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here are the set bonuses:

> (2) Set: Damaging enemies with Arcane, Cold, Fire or Lightning will
>   cause a Meteor of the same damage type to fall from the sky. There is
>   an 8 second cooldown for each damage type.
>
> (4) Set: Arcane, Cold, Fire, and Lightning attacks each increase all
>   of your resistances by 25% for 8 seconds.
>
> (6) Set: Attacks increase your damage by 750% for 8 seconds. Arcane,
>   Cold, Fire, and Lightning attacks each add one stack. At 4 stacks,
>   each different elemental attack extends the duration by 2 seconds, up
>   to a maximum of 8 seconds.

As you can see, the (2) bonus explicitly says damaging, while the other 2 set bonuses state "attacks". therefore, I interpret these set bonuses as both triggering from the same events.